# VueJs Endless loop with computed variable using in v-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, infinite-loop, vuetify.js

I'm try to use a computed value in a v-select (from vuetify) and when I select a value in the select there is an endless loop.

I've reproduce [my dirty code in this pen](https://codepen.io/tyzef/pen/XewKmx) to illustrate my problem. Be careful this might block your navigator.

#### HTML code

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card color="grey lighten-4" flat>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-select
          v-model="select"
          label="Be careful when select a value :)"
          chips
          tags
          :items="items">
        </v-select>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

#### JS Code

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      obj: {
        values: [{'name':'Testing'}]
      },
      items: [
        'Programming',
        'Design',
        'Vue',
        'Vuetify'
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    select: {
      get: function () {
        return this.obj.values.map(val => val.name).sort()
      },
      set: function (chipsValues) {
        this.obj.values = chipsValues.map(val => {return {'name': val}})
      }
    }
  }
})
```

What's the proper way to code this behavior ?

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix would be to validate before setting the `this.obj.values` whether you are getting any new values. If the new value is larger/smaller than old value, you can set it, else ignore it.

Since Javascript is synchronous, you can get away with just checking the length of the arrays.

```
set: function (chipsValues) {
    if( this.obj.values.length != chipsValues.length) {
        this.obj.values = chipsValues.map(val => {return {'name': val}})
    }
}
```

Here's the updated pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XewjdJ?editors=1010

Comment: OK it's works fine. Thank you very much. Can you explain why it do a SET more than once ?

Comment: @tyzef It's probably the way `v-select` is implemented. I would guess that setting a new value would still trigger a getter call to render the chips. IMO `select` might be better as an array in `this.data`, while `obj.values` should be a computed.